# Java Key Bindings using Groovy Swing Builder

Tags: swing, groovy, binding, key, builder

I am trying to write in Groovy application, using "Calculator like" keys functionality. So I would like swing action to be invoked, when I:

- press JButton
- press corresponding keyboard key, no matther whether there is focus on JButton or not.

Probably the best solution is to use Java Key Bindings, as described here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

Following combination of Groovy and Java seems to work well:

```
package packageSwingTest4
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import javax.swing.*
import java.awt.*
import javax.swing.WindowConstants as WC
class SwingTest4 {
    def static b
    static void main(args) { 
        def swing = new SwingBuilder()      
        def f2Action = swing.action(name:"F2", shortDescription:"F2 button", accelerator:"F2") {
        println "F2 pressed"
        }

        swing.edt {
        def f=frame(title: 'Keborad Binding test', size:[400,300],defaultCloseOperation: JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE, show: true) {
                panel {
                b = button(text: 'F2', actionPerformed:{println "FFFF2222 pressed"})
                b.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F2"),"F2 pressed")
                b.getActionMap().put("F2 pressed",f2Action)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

But I do not like to combine Groovy/Java in this way, namely as I will:
- loose nice structure of Groovy code related to structure of GUI
- I have to define Actions separately and not "nicely" as in case of Groovy swing builder

Do you know about "cleaner" solution of my problem using pure Groovy/ SwingBuilder? I would prefer to use Key Bindings, not Key Listener..

Thank you for help and recommendations

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure, but do you mean like this:

```
import groovy.swing.*
import javax.swing.*

def swing = new SwingBuilder()     

def f2Action = swing.action(name:"F2 text", shortDescription:"F2 button", keyStroke:"F2") {
    println "F2 pressed"
} 

swing.edt {
    frame(title: 'Keborad Binding test', size:[400,300],defaultCloseOperation: JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE, show: true) {
        panel {
            button(text: 'F2',
                   actionPerformed:{ println "FFFF2222 pressed" }) {
                action(f2Action)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the solution, which I was looking for. Thank you for fast esponse. My simpified final code is following:

Answer (score 0):

```
        def swing = new SwingBuilder()

        def f2Action = swing.action(name:"F2 text", shortDescription:"F2 button", focus: JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW, keyStroke:"F2") {
        println "F2 pressed"
    }
        def f3Action = swing.action(name:"F3 text", shortDescription:"F2 button", keyStroke:"F3") {
        println "F3 pressed"
    }

        swing.edt {
        frame(title: 'Keborad Binding test', size:[400,300],defaultCloseOperation: JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE, show: true) {
                panel {
                        button('F2') {action(f2Action)}
                        button('F3') {action(f3Action)}
            }
            }
        }
```